# Embed interactive 3d in Website

Tags: html, canvas, web, 3d, webgl

I have to develop a website of a residential building project. The client asked me to embed an interactive 3D view of the model project into the website. The model must be interactive and all available flats color different from the already booked flats. And on hovering the mouse on it, the details will be fetched from the database and will be displayed outside the 3D view.

Thats the whole scenario. Now I need some guidance or an starting point that which 3d library should I use. Because it must be compatible with all major desktop and mobile browsers and no external plugin required.

I have searched on Google and found some libraries:

1. [WebGL](http://www.khronos.org/webgl/)
2. [three.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/)

But I don't know which one will be suitable for the project. If any other most supportable library exists, please inform me. Or just give me a way to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebGL itself is not a library, its the technology that is used by libraries like three.js etc.
Without any knowledge on 3D programming you should take a library like three.js or microsofts babylon.

> it must be compatible with all major desktop and mobile browsers

WebGL is not supported by IE < 11 and also the only mobile browser that supports webgl is chrome on android that just recently became the standard browser on android >= 4.4 (KitKat) so has a rather low coverage.

Also (stock)iOS has **no** app supporting webgl.

Comment: After getting no response !! I started learning X3dom. So what would you suggest me to choose among **x3dom** and **microsoft babylon.js**?

Comment: These are two totally different approaches to 3d in the browser. Three.js and Babylon.js will give you way more control but will propably require a longer and steeper learning curve where as x3dom is basically markup but by this "feature" also rather limited. If you can achieve your goals using x3dom i would suggest sticking with it.
Still you wont get any iOS and internet explorer (except 11) support. I've not used any of the mentioned libraries so this is just my expectation, you'll need to evaluate them against your usecase.